How to Create and Visualize a Directed Weighted Graph with Parallel Edges and Different Weights Using Python?
I'm working on a project where I need to create a directed weighted graph in Python that allows parallel edges with different weights between nodes. I am using the networkx library and Matplotlib for visualization.
My goal is to:

Create a directed graph with parallel edges (multiple edges between the same nodes).
Assign random weights to these edges.
Visualize the graph with edge labels showing the weights.

import random
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def create_graph(n_nodes, alpha = 0.5):
    G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
    G.add_nodes_from(range(n_nodes))
    for i in range(n_nodes):
        for j in range(i+1,n_nodes):
            if random.random() < alpha:
                weight=random.randint(1,10)
                G.add_edge(i, j, weight=weight)

            if random.random() < alpha:
                weight=random.randint(1,10)
                G.add_edge(j, i, weight=weight)
    return G
  

def display_graph(G):
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G)  
    weight_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')  
    nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_color='skyblue', edge_color='gray', node_size=700)
    nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=weight_labels)  
    plt.show()


n_nodes = 5
G = create_graph(n_nodes, alpha = 0.5)
display_graph(G)

However, when I try to visualize the graph with edge labels, I got this error message:
networkx.exception.NetworkXError: draw_networkx_edge_labels does not support multiedges.

This error occurs when I try to display edge labels for a MultiDiGraph, and it seems like the draw_networkx_edge_labels function doesn't support parallel edges.

How can I resolve this error and properly visualize a directed weighted graph with parallel edges?
Is there a better way to create and visualize directed graphs with parallel edges in networkx?

I'd appreciate any guidance or examples to help me achieve this. Thank you in advance!

Do note that in this particular example you could just use a networkx.DiGraph to represent the network, as node pairs are only iterated over once.

A core issue of Networkx's drawing utilities is that they are separated into different functions. For labeling multi-graph edges, the function that determines the location of the edge label (draw_networkx_edge_labels) requires knowledge of the edge path; however, the edge path is computed in draw_networkx_edges and there is no cross-talk between the two.
To work around this and other design issues of the Networkx drawing utilities, I wrote a drop-in replacement called Netgraph. Multi-graph support, however, is pretty new so you have to install from the dev branch (stable releases are distributed via pip and conda-forge):
pip install https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph/archive/dev.zip


import random
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from netgraph import MultiGraph

def create_graph(n_nodes, alpha = 0.5):
    G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
    G.add_nodes_from(range(n_nodes))
    for i in range(n_nodes):
        for j in range(i+1,n_nodes):
            if random.random() < alpha:
                weight=random.randint(1,10)
                G.add_edge(i, j, weight=weight)

            if random.random() < alpha:
                weight=random.randint(1,10)
                G.add_edge(j, i, weight=weight)
    return G

G = create_graph(5)
MultiGraph(
    G,
    node_labels=True,
    node_color="skyblue",
    edge_color="gray",
    edge_labels=nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight'),
    edge_label_fontdict=dict(fontsize=8),
    arrows=True,
)
plt.show()



This is a great alternative. Thank you!

Here is a solution with gravis. In this case it's inside a Jupyter notebook and the graph is displayed in the output cell.
Disclaimer: I'm the author of the package.
import random

import gravis as gv
import networkx as nx


def create_graph(n_nodes, alpha = 0.5):
    g = nx.MultiDiGraph()
    g.add_nodes_from(range(n_nodes))
    for i in range(n_nodes):
        for j in range(i+1,n_nodes):
            if random.random() < alpha:
                weight = random.randint(1, 5)
                g.add_edge(i, j, size=weight)

            if random.random() < alpha:
                weight = random.randint(1, 5)
                g.add_edge(j, i, size=weight)
    return g
  

def display_graph(g):
    # Properties across the whole graph
    g.graph["node_color"] = "skyblue"
    g.graph["edge_color"] = "gray"
    g.graph["node_size"] = 30
    g.graph["node_label_size"] = 20
    
    # Properties for individual elements
    pos = nx.spring_layout(g)
    scaling_factor = 300
    for node, (x, y) in pos.items():
        g.nodes[node]["x"] = x * scaling_factor
        g.nodes[node]["y"] = y * scaling_factor
    return gv.d3(g, edge_curvature=0.1)


n_nodes = 10
g = create_graph(n_nodes, alpha = 0.5)
display_graph(g)


The package can also be used in CPython, e.g. with the following code opening the graph in a browser window:
fig = gv.d3(g, edge_curvature=0.1)
fig.display()

